# Compound usage of bind(this) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to implement a complicated data structure which requires modification of scope inside various functions. Then, I came across `function.prototype.bind()`. At first, I thought it was very useful. But, some of the results are unexpected. So, I wrote a demo code for testing and here is the code.

```
(function () {

    this.t = 9.8765432

    this.a = (function(){
        this.t = 3.14159
        this.b = (function(){return this.t;}).bind(this)
        this.c = (function(){
            this.t=1.23456
            this.d=(function(){return t;}).bind(this)
            return this
        })()
        return this
    })()

    console.log(this.a.b()) //My guess was 3.14159, at the end it is 1.23456
    console.log((this.a.b.bind(this))()) //My guess was 9.8765432, at the end it is 1.23456
    console.log(this.a.c.d()) //My guess was 1.23456, at the end it is 1.23456
    console.log((this.a.c.d.bind(this))()) //My guess was 9.8765432, at the end it is 1.23456

    return this
})();
```

Sadly, I guessed all the results incorrectly. This indicates I don't have enough understanding of this function. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Modifying scope is pretty complicated for someone who's new. Heck, I'm experienced and I still won't touch scope. Are you sure you need to do it?

Comment: Note that the code heavily relies on the fact that it is not run in strict mode: https://jsfiddle.net/2wd83dw5/. Outside of strict mode the `this` context of a function invocation which is not on an object (e.g. `(function() { ... })()` is `undefined`.

Comment: I am trying to emulate a filesystem in javascript. To implement mkdir and ls, I added functions corresponding to the two commands using bind(this) in each directory object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not creating any objects for `this` to refer to. Thus `this` just refers to the global `window` object everywhere in your code (it would be `undefined` in strict mode). Since you only have one object, you only have one `t` property which has most recently been assigned the value `1.23456`. The previous assignments were overwritten by the most recent assignment.

Try your test with the new keyword instead of IIFEs at each scope. This will create three separate objects for `this` at different scopes, instead of using the global object:

```js
new function () {

    this.t = 9.8765432

    this.a = new function(){
        this.t = 3.14159;
        this.b = function(){return this.t;}.bind(this);
        this.c = new function(){
            this.t = 1.23456;
            this.d = function(){return this.t;}.bind(this);
            return this;
        };
        return this;
    };

    console.log( this.a.b() ); // My guess was 3.14159
    console.log( this.a.b.bind(this)() ); // My guess was 9.8765432
    console.log( this.a.c.d() ); // My guess was 1.23456
    console.log( this.a.c.d.bind(this)() ); // My guess was 9.8765432

    return this;
};
```

Your first and third guesses are correct. Your second and fourth guesses would be correct if the function hadn't already been bound. Calling `bind` on an already bound function has no effect on it. Removing the inner calls to bind gives you exactly what you expect:

```js
new function () {

    this.t = 9.8765432

    this.a = new function(){
        this.t = 3.14159;
        this.b = function(){return this.t;};
        this.c = new function(){
            this.t = 1.23456;
            this.d = function(){return this.t;};
            return this;
        };
        return this;
    };

    console.log( this.a.b() ); // My guess was 3.14159
    console.log( this.a.b.bind(this)() ); // My guess was 9.8765432
    console.log( this.a.c.d() ); // My guess was 1.23456
    console.log( this.a.c.d.bind(this)() ); // My guess was 9.8765432
    
    return this;
};
```